# issue with restricting a command, discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I looked up the correct permission but It still raises an error on exec

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(mute_members = True)
async def ping(ctx):
    bping = round(client.latency * 1000)
    stringping = str(bping)
    await ctx.send(stringping + "ms")
```

Error
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions: You are missing Mute Members permission(s) to run this command.

So I thought it might be me missing the permissions but thats not the case.
Also my bot has admin perms.

Comment: and yeah its weired I want to restrict a ping command ik its just for testing ;)

Comment: ```from discord.ext import commands```
Commands ext is installed

Comment: ```@commands.has_role(753758073499287612)```
Same with this check... am I doing something fundamentally wrong ?
"discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRole: Role 753758073499287612 is required to run this command."
I 100000000% have the roleee

Comment: Do you have that permission in that channel context?  You might try `has_guild_permissions` instead

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Use has_guild_permissions
Ty Patrick